# Source to learn DNN basics developer

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have gone through many links , but couldn't find a suitable site for learning DotnetNuke basics after deployment. 
Can anyone suggest this ... basic for a developer. how to start, the extension, modules, its usability

Rigin

Comment: what about this site? http://www.dnncreative.com/

Comment: see video library - http://www.dnnsoftware.com/videos and wiki - http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki in dnn site, both links will be enough to get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start is http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/module-development

While the video tutorial series there is old, it is the best thing out there at this time. Though I might be biased, I created it.